# Can't find System.Windows.Vector in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vector, namespaces

I'm making a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but can't get the built-in Vector to work.

Microsoft says that there is a [`System.Windows.Vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx) in the .NET Framework 4:

Maybe I'm making some large mistake, but Visual Studio complains about trying to use Vector in any way, and it doesn't come up in the IntelliSense autocomplete:

The line `Vector v = new Vector(20, 30);` gives

> Compile error Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Vector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I tried including a `using System.Windows` at the top but that didn't solve the problem.

I went to References -> Add Reference to try to find something to add, but nothing was obvious.

The problem may be: Also listed with `Vector` in the [`System.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599716%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace, there are other classes like `Rect` or `Application`. I could use these as `System.Drawing.Rectangle` or `System.Windows.Forms.Application`, but **none of these show up as part of some System.Windows namespace**

I've tried different things for about 2 hours, and found [this related post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c32d6e27-0516-42bc-a065-e9ca99c72d78/) (but Vector **is** part of .NET 4, so their fix doesn't seem worthwhile?) and [this possibly related post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/fdfff143-c1ae-41cd-bbeb-8ff6c1c879ec) but I do have .NET Framework 4 installed.

Does anyone have an example of `Vector`? I know I could get a third party class, but I feel I'm missing something, and want to learn/have the solution posted for other people googling the same problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a reference to **WindowsBase**.
The `Vector` class is defined in the WindowsBase.dll assembly within the System.Windows namespace.

Comment: Works great!
I can't use the System.Windows namespace without creating ambiguity, but that's not a huge problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: I had a hard time finding WindowsBase until I realized that my target environment was .NET 2.0, so just as a heads up, make sure that you are using .NET 4.0 or newer to be able to add that reference.

Answer (score 9):

[`System.Windows.Vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx) is a part of WPF, not Windows Forms, hence the difficulty you've having when trying to use it. You *could* add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll`, but given that it's intended for use in WPF applications, rather than Windows Forms applications, it's likely that you'd derive little benefit from doing so.

Microsofts decision to put WPF components in `System.Windows` and WinForms in `System.Windows.Forms` is a source of endless confusion on the internet, quite what was wrong with `System.Windows.Presentation` or similar for WPF, I'll never know!

Answer (score 2):

To find out which assembly you have to add to your references, it can be very helpful to use a tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) (OpenSource). There you can search for the type you need, and find out in which assembly it is implemented and which namespace you have to use.

Finding out the implementing assembly can be quite difficult, and i have to do it often. I found it to be a fast method and thought it can help you in the future.

Comment: System.Windows.Vector is a class, not a namespace. There's nothing even remotely namespace related.

Comment: @Rob - Sorry, you are absolutely right and i will edit my answer. Nevertheless, it can be a real help to find the assembly and the namespace of a type.